# Opensolaris, ZFS shares

Tags: authentication, zfs, opensolaris

I've recently updated to OpenSolaris 2010.05 from 2009.06. Its currently set up to share one of the the ZFS zpools to the other machines on my network. However, only a single account is able to access these shares. My other accounts get refused when attempting to connect.

File permissions are all correct - When logging into the machine directly with the other logins, I can see, and play with the files and directories as normal - Its just the share that gets refused.

I have entries for all users in the /var/smb/smbpasswd file.

The interesting thing is, I could access the shares prior to upgrading. Nothing else was changed other than the straight upgrade. I am pretty sure there is no user specific sharing going on. What could be preventing others from accessing this zpool?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure /var/smb/smbpasswd and /etc/passwd are in sync for these users.

Comment: I've got entries for the user in both of them. To make sure, I reran passwd for the failing user.

Comment: Anything of interest in the system logs ? (/var/adm/messages)